# (How) Can I select all of the 'content' of the corpus rather than just specific [[1]] or [[2]] etc?

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I want to select all of the corpus content to analyse as a whole, rather than just one at a time, how can I alter this code?

Tried selecting one at a time but have 70 documents to analyse and I want to look at them as a whole

```
ReportCorpus[[1]]$content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` together with content. See code below with crude as an example. This will print everything as a list (or if you want to store it as a list)

```
library(tm)

data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)

lapply(crude, content)
```